# With ω=se^iφ, where s≥0 and φ∈ , solve the equation z^n=ω in C where n is a natural number. How many solutions are there?

Tags: complex-analysis

With $ω=se^{iφ}$, where $s≥0$ and φ∈ , solve the equation $z^n=ω$ in C where n is a natural number. How many solutions are there?

I have the solutions to this problem however, do not understand its steps.

I do not understand how $z=s^\frac 1n e^{(i\frac \phi n+\frac{2kpi}n)}$ where $k \in Z$.

Where is the $2k\pi$ coming from?

Any verification will help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html), $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

So, $e^{2k\pi i}=\cos {2k\pi}+i\sin {2k\pi}=1$ if $k$ is any integer.

$ω=se^{i\phi}$

$z^n=w=se^{i\phi}$

This is an $n-$degree equation in $z,$ so has $n$ solutions.

$z^n=se^{i\phi}\cdot1=se^{i\phi}e^{2k\pi i}=se^{i(\phi+2k\pi)}$

$z=s^{\frac 1 n}e^{\frac{i(\phi+2k\pi)}n} $ where $0\le k <n$, more generally  any $n$ in-congruent values of $k$ will give us essentially the same set of $n$ distinct solutions, find the explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743) .