# The n-th derivative of $x \cdot \cos(2x)$

Tags: derivatives

I have a function $f(x) = x \cdot \cos(2x)$. I have to find the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}(x)$.

I know I have to use Leibnitz's formula, but how to get a general formula for this $f(x)$?

Comment: Do a few cases.. A pattern should emerge.

Comment: See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls_ecEhUDJo

Comment: For your work, the result is given by $$1/2\,{2}^{n} \left( \sin \left( 2\,x+1/2\,n\pi  \right) n+2\,\cos
 \left( 2\,x+1/2\,n\pi  \right) x \right) 
$$

Comment: So, what is now explicit formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$? $f^{(n)}(x) = ...$

Comment: Because the Leibnitz formula: $$(gh)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}g^{(k)}h^{(n - k)}$$, where $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = \cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{d^n(x\cos2x)}{dx^n }=\binom n0x\dfrac{d^n(\cos2x)}{dx^n }+\binom n0\dfrac{dx}{dx}\dfrac{d^{n-1}(\cos2x)}{dx^{n-1} }+0$$

as $\dfrac{d^r(x)}{dx^r}=0$ for $r\ge2$

**Method** $\#1:$

Now like [$100$-th derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{x}\cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752455/100-th-derivative-of-the-function-fx-ex-cosx/1752462#1752462),

$\cos ax$ is the real part of $e^{iax}$

$$\dfrac{d^m(e^{iax})}{dx^m}=(ia)^me^{iax}=a^m(\cos ax+i\sin ax)\left(\cos\dfrac\pi2+i\sin\dfrac\pi2\right)^m$$

Use [De Moivre's Theorem Related - Complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335666/de-moivres-theorem-related-complex-number/335668) to find the real part

**Method** $\#2:$

$\dfrac{d(\cos2x)}{dx}=-\sin2x=\cos\left(2x+\dfrac\pi2\right)$

$\dfrac{d^2(\cos2x)}{dx^2}=-\cos2x=\cos\left(2x+2\cdot\dfrac\pi2\right)$

Observe that $\dfrac{d^m(\cos2x)}{dx^m}$ has a period of $4$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d^n(xe^{i2x})}{dx^n}=x(2i)^ne^{i2x}+n(2i)^{n-1}e^{i2x}$

Compare the real parts.