# Help with trigonometry identity derivation

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me with a complicated trigonometry derivation with only basic trigonometric identities:

$$\csc^2 \bigg(\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) + \csc^2 \bigg(2\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) + \csc^2 \bigg(3\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) = 8$$

Thanks...

Comment: is this the identity you want help with? $$\csc^2 \bigg(\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) + \csc^2 \bigg(2\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) + \csc^2 \bigg(3\frac{\pi}{7}\bigg) = 8$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks.... I suck at Latex(really need some practice)... Thanks:)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265229/prove-that-cot2-pi-7-cot22-pi-7-cot23-pi-7-5  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470614/find-the-value-of-textrmcosec2-left-frac-pi7-right-textrmcosec2-left