# Trigonometry : Find the value of $\csc^2 \pi/7 + \csc^2 2\pi/7 + \csc^2 3\pi/7$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\csc^2 \pi/7 + \csc^2 2\pi/7 + \csc^2 3\pi/7$

My try : Converted it into Sin and then tried to apply series formula but failed

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. For a proficient interaction, please take a few minutes to learn type MathJax.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's not a duplicate just want to know the answer I was confused whether 3pi/7 and 4pi/7 are same or not in case of cosec

Comment: @user580093 This is the same, 'cause $\csc^2(\pi - x) = \csc^2 (x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The same question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470614/find-the-value-of-textrmcosec2-left-frac-pi7-right-textrmcosec2-left?rq=1) with $\csc^2(4\pi/7)$ instead of $\csc^2(3\pi/7)$.

Comment: ...which is the same thing, one might add (since $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$).

Answer (score 0):

I provide one more solution. Judging by the question you asked, I'm assuming your manipulation of $\tan$ and $\cot$ need to reinforce.

First, some preparation.

We all know that 
$$
\tan (x \pm y) = \frac {\tan (x) \pm \tan (y)} {1 \mp \tan (x)\tan (y)}. 
$$
Then 
$$
\cot (x - y) = \frac {\cot (x) \cot (y) + 1} { \cot (y) - \cot (x)},
$$
or
$$
\cot (x) \cot (y) = \cot(x-y) (\cot(y) -\cot(x)) - 1
$$
Especially,
$$
\cot (2x) = \frac {\cot^2 (x) -1} {2 \cot (x)},
$$
which yields
$$
\cot^2(x) - 1 = 2\cot(x)\cot(2x).
$$
Also, 
$$
\csc^2(x) = \frac {\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)} {\sin ^2(x)} = 1 + \cot^2(x).
$$
Now let's start. Let $x = \pi /7$.
$$
P := \csc^2(x) + \csc^2(2x) + \csc^2(4x) = 3 + \cot^2(x) + \cot^2(2x) + \cot^2(3x).
$$
By the formula above, 
$$
P = 6 + 2(\cot(x) \cot(2x) + \cot(2x) \cot (4x) + \cot (4x) \cot (8x)) =: 6 +2Q. 
$$
Now change the angle: since $\cot(\pi \pm y) = \mp\cot (y)$, we have
$$
Q = \cot(x)\cot(2x) - \cot(2x) \cot (3x) - \cot(3x) \cot (x).
$$
Now,
\begin{align*}
Q &= 1+ \cot(x)(\cot(x) - \cot(2x)) - \cot(x) (\cot(2x) -\cot(3x)) - \cot(2x)(\cot(x) - \cot (3x))\\
&=   1+  \cot(x) (\cot(x) -3\cot(2x) + \cot(3x)) + \cot(2x) \cot(3x)\\
&=  \cot(x) (\cot(x) -3\cot(2x) + \cot(3x)) + (\cot(2x)-\cot(3x))\cot(x) \\
&= \cot(x)(\cot(x) -2\cot(2x))\\
&= \cot^2(x) - 2\cot(2x) \cot(x)\\
&=1.
\end{align*}
Therefore $P = 6+2Q=8$.