# Natural number n-Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, arithmetic

The number of natural number $n$ in the interval $[1005,2010]$ for which the polynomial

$$1+x+x^2+x^3\dots +x^{(n-1)}$$ divides the polynomial $$1+x^2+x^4\dots+x^{2010}$$ is:

I could realize that the terms in the two polynomials are in GP and I applied the sum to n terms of a GP formula and then divided both the polynomials.

What I get is $(x^{2010}-1)/(x^{n}-1)$.

Now how to proceed?

Comment: Your second formula is a sum over $x^{2n}$ instead of $x^n$, how does that affect this scenario?  Also, isn't the final formula with $2011$ and $n+1$?

Comment: yeah got the mistake but my ans comes out to be (x^(2012)-1)/(x+1)(x^(n)-1)......but not able to proceed further..now how to proceed?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR I made lots of edits but still need your refinement to make sense to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1), $$(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{(n,m)}-1$$

$$\implies (a^m-1)|(a^n-1)\iff m|n$$

$$\implies (x^n-1)|(x^{2012}-1)\iff n|2012$$

Now, the factors of  $2012 $ are $n=1,2,4,503,1006,2012$

Observe that $\displaystyle\frac{x^{2012}-1}{x^n-1}$ must have $(x+1)$ as factor

and we know from (1) of  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743), $ x^m=1$ does not have a repeated root

If $n$ is even, $(x^{2012}-1,x^n-1)$ will be divisible by $x^2-1,$ hence by 
$x+1$

$\implies (x+1)$ will not divide $\displaystyle\frac{x^{2012}-1}{x^n-1}$

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, could you please share the source of the Question and also verify the answer.

Comment: All those questions(including this) are questions that came in KVPY scholarship exam....I'm preparing for it....

Comment: sir the answer is given to be 503...but there is also an option with 0 as the answer.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR, $1$ is also a valid answer. Method is more important than the answer.

Comment: So what is the answer?