# The number of natural number $n$ in the interval of [$1005,2010$ ] for which the polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The number of natural number $n$ in the interval of [$1005,2010$ ] for which the polynomial $1$+$x$+$x^2$+ $x^3$ +...+$x^{n-1}$ divides the polynomial   $1$+$x^2$+$x^4$+$x^6$ ....+$x^{2010}$ is

Ans is the number of such numbers is 503.

My soln:
$$ (x^{503}-1)(x^{503} +1)( x^{1006}+1) $$ to be 
Divided by $ x^n -1$ So n=503.

Comment: Contest problem from which contest in 2010?  Please cite the source of such problems statements.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It is kvpy 2010 exam. I am gettin n=503, but the question and its official answer key state answer as 503 as number of numbers within the interval as 503. I need to check so what is suppose to be correct answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The answer should be the *number* of such numbers, so 503 makes sense. However, I have a strong suspicion this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, I misread the question.

Comment: I did write it as $x^{503}-1 {1-x+x^2.....}{ 1+x^{1006}$ which now needs to be divided by $x^{n}-1$

Comment: If we have the asked divisibility of polynomials, then, since they are monic, the quotient must be an integer polynomial. In particular, we must also have a divisibility of values: for $x=1$, we get that $n$ should divide $1006$, and in the given interval there is only one such value.

Comment: What value is that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475084/natural-number-n-divisibility

Comment: @bhattachargee i asked same q there also? So the given official answer key was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}$ divides $1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{2010}$ exactly when
$$
(x^n-1)=(x-1)(1+x+...+x^{n-1})|(x-1)(1+x^2+x^4+...)=\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}(1+x^2+...+x^{2010})=\frac{x^{2012}-1}{x+1}.
$$

If the polynomial $x^n-1$ divides the polynomial $\frac{x^{2012}-1}{x+1},$ then all the (complex) roots of $x^n-1$ must also be roots of $x^{2012}-1,$ but $x=-1$ cannot be a root of $x^n-1.$. Because $-1$ is a root of $x^n-1$ when $n$ is even, the value $n$ must be odd. If $n$ is odd, then it is sufficient that $x^n-1|x^{2012}-1.$ But the complex roots of $x^n-1$ are shared by $x^{2012}-1$ exactly when $n$ divides $2012$. The only value $n$ in the range $[1005, 2010]$ for which this happens is $1006$, but this even, so there are zero solutions for $n$ in the range $[1005,2010].$

Comment: Why dont your solution considers n=503? For n=503 second polynomial does divide first . Also common ratio of one of the terms of x^2

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question the first time I posted, and then I had some errors to fix. Now my solution shows that the first polynomial divides the second when $n$ is any odd divisor of  $2012.$ But since $1006$ is even and not odd, it doesn't make the cut.

Comment: How odd n elliminated? Also n=503 is valid solution.

Comment: The even $n$ are eliminated. The odd $n$ are valid solutions. If $n$ is even then $-1$ is a root of $1+x+...+x^{n-1}$ so it contains $(x+1)$ as a factor. But $-1$ is not a root of $1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{2010}$ so this polynomial does not contain $(1+x)$ as a factor. Therefore if $n$ is even the first polynomial cannot divide the second.

Comment: @maveric $n = 503$ would be a solution except it is not in $[1005, 2010]$

Answer (score -1):

If $f(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}$ divides $g(x)=1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{2010}$, then the quotient has integer coefficients. Therefore, $n=f(1)$ divides $1006=g(1)$. There is only one multiple of $1006$ in $[1005,2010]$, which is $1006$ itself. Thus, the only possible solution, if there is a solution, is $n=1006$.

Comment: I'm not sure why people downvoted this response. Seems perfectly legit to me, even if it does not resolve the question of whether or not $n=1006$ is a solution (it is not).