# Factor the polynomial $x^3 − 27$ using De Moivre's theorem (Please explain solution)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I was reading the book A First Course in Linear Algebra by Ken Kuttler (link to nearly identical page http://librarum.org/book/312/11) and I did not understand this part:

Q: Factor the polynomial $x^3 − 27$.

A: Solution. First find the cube roots of $27$. By the above procedure using De Moivre’s theorem, these cube roots are $3$, $3(-1/2 + i \sqrt{3}/2)$, and $3(-1/2 - i\sqrt{3}/2)$.

Unfortunately, I did look at the "above procedure" (see link if necessary) and still don't really know what happened. What exactly are the steps to get the $3$ roots? Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube roots $z_k,\; k=0,1,2$ of $a>0$ (in your case $a=27$) are:
$$z_k=\sqrt[3]{a}e^{2ik\pi/3}$$

and notice that $z_0$ is real and $z_1,z_2$ are conjugate so 
$$x^3-a=(x-z_0)(x-z_1)(x-z_2)=(x-z_0)(x^2-2\mathrm{Re}(z_1)x+|z_1|^2)\\=(x-\sqrt[3]{a})(x^2+\sqrt[3]{a}x+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2)$$

Comment: Thank you!! After some consideration (I'm not that good at math), I understood what you wrote and fully understand that part of my textbook now. :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This needs an UV! +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that $27=3^3$ and write $u=x/3$ to get
$$
x^3 − 27=3^3(u^3-1)=3^3(u-1)(u-\omega)(u-\omega^2)=(3u-3)(3u-3\omega)(u-3\omega^2)=(x-3)(x-3\omega)(x-3\omega^2)
$$