# What is the sum of non-real roots of the polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials

What is the sum of non-real roots of the polynomial equation $X^{3}+3X^{2}+3X+3=0$ ?

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the left hand side of your equation.

Since 
$$(x+1)^3=-2,$$
we know one real solution is 
$$x=-1-\sqrt[3]{2}.$$

We know the other solutions are non-real solutions(Why?).

Now by Vieta's formulas,
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-3$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the solutions of $f(x)=0.$

Then?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$x^3+3x^2+3x+3=(x+1)^3+2$$

In case you don't know about the roots of $y^3=-2,$ you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1)