# Finding the solution to $x^3 = 3px + 2q$

Tags: calculus

Solve $x^3 = 3px + 2q$ when $q^2 < p^3$ by the substitution $x = 2 \sqrt{p} \cos(\theta)$. The solutions are given by $x = 2 \sqrt{p} \cos(\frac{1}{3}(\phi + 2k\pi))$ for $k = 0,1,2$ where $\cos\phi = \frac{q}{p\sqrt{p}}$

I have made the subsitution to get:

$$8p^{\frac{3}{2}} (\cos(\theta))^3 = 6p^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos(\theta) + 2q $$
$$ q = 4p^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos(\theta))^3 - 3p^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos(\theta)$$

$ q = p^{\frac{3}{2}} \cos(3 \theta)$
(this last identity I got from a previous question)

$$\frac{q}{p^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \cos(3 \theta)$$

I am unsure how to proceed from here, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You have done the hard work,

let $\displaystyle\cos\phi=\frac q{p^{\frac32}}$ which is possible iff $\displaystyle-1\le \frac q{p^{\frac32}}\le 1\iff 0\le \frac{q^2}{p^3}\le1$

If $p>0$ and $ q^2\le p^3$ (which is given)

So, we have $\displaystyle\cos3\theta=\cos\phi\implies 3\theta=2n\pi\pm\phi$ where $n$ is any integer

$\displaystyle\implies \theta=\frac{2n\pi\pm\phi}3 $ where $n$ can assume any three [in-congruent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743) values $\pmod3$ when either '+' or '-' sign is considered as there are exactly three roots