# Fourth roots of $-17$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question I'm stuck on is as follows:

Find all $4$th roots of $−17$ in Cartesian form. Simplify as much as possible.

Here's what I've done so far:

$$z^4 = -17\\
|z| = \sqrt{(-17)^2} = 17 = r\\$$Using De Moivre's Theorem:$$
-17 = 17e^{0i +2kπi}\\
-17^{\frac{1}{4}} =17^\frac{1}{4}[e^{2kπi}]^\frac{1}{4}\\
17^\frac{1}{4}[e^{2k}]^{\frac{π}{4}i}\\
z_0 = 17^\frac{1}{4}[\cos(0)+\sin(0)i] = 17^\frac{1}{4}\\
z_1 = 17^\frac{1}{4}[\cos\left(\frac{π}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)i] = 17^\frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: $e^{\pi i}=-1$ might help, although it might be easier to think of introducing the fourth roots of $i$.

Answer (score 2):

The step you have done$|z|$=17 is wrong.As $z^4$ = -17,hence $z^2$ = $\pm$ $\sqrt17$$\times$i.
Case 1:-
For $z^2$ = +$\sqrt17$$\times$i.On square rooting i you will get $\sqrt i$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\times$(1 + i). hence as $z^2$ = +$\sqrt17$$\times$i so z=$\pm$ $\mathrm {17}^{1/4}$$\times$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\times$(1 + i).
Case 2:-
For $z^2$ = -$\sqrt17$$\times$i=$\sqrt17$$\times$(-i).On square rooting -i you will get $\sqrt -i$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\times$(1 - i).Hence z=$\pm$ $\mathrm {17}^{1/4}$$\times$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\times$(1 - i).Therefore z=$\pm$ $\mathrm {17}^{1/4}$$\times$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$\times$(1 $\pm$ i)

Comment: $z^2=\pm i \sqrt{17}$.  $i$ has two square roots, the one you give and its negative.  You should find four fourth roots of $-17$

Comment: I corrected it but due to internet connection problem t didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle -1=e^{i\pi }=e^{(2k+1)\pi i}$ where $k$ is any integer

So,  $\displaystyle -1^{\frac14}=e^{\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}4}$ where $k$ can assume any four [in-congruent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743) values $\pmod4$

Now use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) to get $\displaystyle -1^{\frac14}=\cos\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}4+i\sin\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}4$ where we can take $k$ to be $0,1,2,3$

[de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Applications) should bring us in the destination