# how to solve circle dividing equation (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a equation that should divide a circle in even parts. As I found its called circle-dividing equation. I'v found same information how to solve a equation which has a form like this:

$$z^6 = 1$$

one of the first steps was to transform the equation using MOIVRE to

$$z^6 = 1+0i$$

$\cos(6 \varphi) = 1$  // real number part

$\sin(6 \varphi) = 0$  // imag number part

but my equation is:

$$z^3 = 8i$$

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^3=8i=8e^{\dfrac{i\pi}2}=8e^{\left(2k\pi+\dfrac\pi2\right)i}$$ where $k$ is any integer

$$z=2e^{\dfrac{(4k+1)\pi i}6}$$ where $k\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$ (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656832/fourth-roots-of-17/656835#656835))

Now use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html)

Answer (score 2):

$$r^3(\cos(3\varphi)+i\sin(3\varphi))=8i = 8\left(\cos\frac\pi2+i\sin\frac\pi2\right)$$

So
$$
r^3=8\text{ and }3\varphi=\frac\pi2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** you can rewrite the given equation to
$$
\left(\frac z2\right)^3=i
$$
and solve for $\frac z2$.
You could also rewrite it to
$$
\left(\frac z2 i\right)^3=1
$$
by multiplying both sides with $i^3$.