# Prove that 1 has n distinct roots of order n

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I am trying to show that 1 has n distinct roots of degree n, or in other word that the equations $$z^n=1$$ has n different roots over the complex field.

I know that the fundamental theorem of Algebra ensures me that there are n, but it does not ensure that they are different, so how can I do it?

Thanks

P.S. it's not homework :)

Comment: See the usage of   Repeated Root Theorem,  here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743

Comment: Hint: Mr. Moivre might know the answer.

Comment: You meant Monsieur Moivre

Comment: Think geometrically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ are pairwise distinct roots of an $n$-th degree polynomial $p(z)$ then they all have multiplicity 1 and there are no other roots. This I hope is clear, and if not I can explain it further.

The numbers $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ defined by
$$z_k = \cos(2 \pi k / n) + i \sin (2 \pi k / n)$$
are all roots of $z^n - 1$ by Moivre's formula. They are also pairwise distinct. Therefore, they are the only roots of $z^n - 1$.

In short, we guess $n$ pairwise distinct roots of $z^n = 1$, and then we conclude that there cannot be any others.

Answer (score 0):

A multiple root of $f(x)$ is also a root of $f'(x)$ (simply because the derivative of $f(x)=(x-a)^2g(x)$ is $f'(x)=2(x-a)g(x)+(x-a)^2g'(x)$). You can compute $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))$ with the euklidean algorithm. In this case simply $\gcd(f(x),f'(x)) = \gcd(x^n-1,nx^{n-1})=1$ because $\frac 1nxf'(x)-f(x)=1$.