# Problem about complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all values of $(-1)^{1/3}$
I used the identity's and such and got a part where I got $e^{1/3\log(-1)}$, and I'm not sure how to do the next step and get to the answer.
Can anyone send in the right direction ?

Comment: Do you know about the nth roots of unity?

Comment: Yes I used it, and i got the principle axis which equals = 1/2 + sqrt(3)i/2 But the answer to the question is  = e^i*pi/3 , e^i*pi and e^(i*5pi/3) and Im not sure how they got that

Comment: just write them in the form of e^ix where x is the angle.... The answers do match.

Comment: @Vishwjit, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-1 = e^{i\pi}$$

so

$$\sqrt[3]{-1} = e^{i\pi/3}$$

is your first solution. The other two are obtained by adding integer multiples of $2\pi/3$ in the exponential ($e^{ix}$ is $2\pi$-periodic). The general solution is then

$$\sqrt[3]{-1} = e^{i\pi/3 + ik 2\pi/3}$$

for $k = 0,1,2$.

Comment: Thank you! that is perfect explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A fast but non-rigorous answer could go as follows: Use the polar representation of -1. In general $-1=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$ for every integer k. Assuming that the properties of exponentiation hold also for complex numbers, you would have $(-1)^{1/3}=e^{i(2k\pi/3)+i\pi/3}$. Now the only thing that is left is to identify the different values that the phase $2k\pi/3$ can take, considering that multiples of $2\pi$ produce the same number.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! this helps a lot as well :)