# How to solve $x^3 = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

My intuitive side tells me to take the cube root of both the sides and get the answer $1$. However, I realize that it might be a problem for I'll lose solutions as given here:

[image]

Is it the case that we always need to have a zero on one side to solve equations like this?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1

Comment: If you haven't studied complex numbers then the answer by mathematicsstudent is all you need. Yet the link you post shows all the solutions in $\;\Bbb C\;$ , so: have you studied complex numbers?

Comment: Yes I have. But I never thought of subtracting both sides so that I can factor it later. My intuition told me to take the cube root. How was I supposed to figure out that I was to subtract on both the sides instead of doing it the former way?

Comment: @user331377 One of the first things that are *usually* taught when studying complex numbers in high school (at least here) is to calculate roots of unity of degree $\;n\;$ ,which means solutions to $\;x^n=1\;$, using the polar form of complex numbers, de Moivre's and Euler's formula and etc.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not given in this book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all examsmanship.  Is $x$ supposed to be real?  Then $1$ is the only possibility.  Can $x$ be complex?  Then, as shown on the website there are two more solutions.

**ADDED**: As to how you figure this out, examsmanship includes being able to spot ambiguities in questions -- here "does the exam ask for real roots only or complex ones too?" -- and getting them clarified.  If you're told complex, you can think in terms of "this is a cubic equation, it can have two complex solutions and one real, to solve cubics with one known solution you divide by $(x-$known solution) and apply the quadratic formula to the quotient."  There are other ways to think about finding the complex roots too.  I usually think $\exp(2\pi i/3)$ because I've had exponentials, which you may not have.

Comment: So, how will I know that I am supposed to subtract both the sides by one and then factorize instead of just taking the cube root on both the sides?

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in $\mathbb{R}$, then you can easily find that $x = 1$ is a solution, as you have found.

But what about if we wish to find all soutions, including those in $\mathbb{C}$? How do we know that we haven't lost solutions, or that we have all of them?

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), you know that the equation $x^3 = 1$ (or equivalently, $x^3 - 1 = 0$) has three roots. We already know that $x = 1$ is one of them, so you can use your precalculus knowledge of the factor theorem to factor $x - 1$ out to give $(x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = 0$. Solving the remaining quadratic gives the solutions $x = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ and $x = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}$.

You may also be interested in reading up on [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Answer (score 3):

Taking the cubic root of both sides might yield more solutions than you expect. If you consider the equation $x^2=1$, then taking the squareroot yields $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\sqrt{1}=1$. Hence $x=\pm 1$. So there are actually two solutions.

Similarly, when taking the cubic root of $x^3=1$ there are three solutions, two of which lie in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I tend to take both paths; for $x^3=1$, I take the cube root of both sides to identify a solution, and then divide (maybe with long division) by $(x - \text{one solution})$ to simplify the expression. My goal here is to factor the expression completely.