# Roots of a 6th degree complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the roots of the following equation: $z^6-3z^3+2$

Let's set $z^3=w$

We now have the polynomial: $w^2-3w+2=0$

$\Delta = 1 \implies w_1=1, w_2=2$

$z^3=w$ \implies:

$z_1= 1, z_2= $  $\sqrt[3]{2}$

I don't know how to find the other roots

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{C}$, you know that $z^3=1$ has *three* solutions, as does $z^3=2$. This gives you the six solutions you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You work is correct but not complete. For $z^3=1$ you have:
$$
z^3-1=0 \quad \iff \quad (z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0
$$
so you have the solution $z=1$ but also $z=\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm i\sqrt{3})$ that are the roots of the second degree factor. And do the same for $z^3=2$.

Comment: Once you know the roots of $z^3-1$, you can also simply multiply them by $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: How did you factorise into $(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0$? how did you find the z^2+z+1 ? In this case is there an easier method than polynomial long division