# For $z\in\mathbb{C}, |z|=1$, Prove that $\Big(\frac{1+ia}{1-ia}\Big)^4=z$ has all roots real and distinct

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$, then prove that the equation $\Big(\dfrac{1+ia}{1-ia}\Big)^4=z$ has all roots real and distinct

**My Attempt**
$$
z=e^{i\theta}\implies z^{1/4}=e^{i\theta/4}=\frac{1+ia}{1-ia}.1^{1/4}=\frac{1+ia}{1-ia}.(1,-1,i,-i)
$$
Is it correct to introduce the quadratic root of unity for the complete solution ?

Case 1: $1^{1/4}=1$
$$
\frac{1}{ia}=\frac{e^{i\theta/4}+1}{e^{i\theta/4}-1}=\frac{2\cos^2\theta/8+2i\sin\theta/8.\cos\theta/8}{-2\sin^2\theta/8+2i\sin\theta/8.\cos\theta/8}\\
\frac{1}{ia}=i\cot\theta/8\\\boxed{a=-\tan\theta/8}
$$
Case 2: $1^{1/4}=-1$
$$
\frac{1}{ia}=\frac{-e^{i\theta/4}+1}{-e^{i\theta/4}-1}=\frac{2\sin^2\theta/8-2i\sin\theta/8.\cos\theta/8}{-2\cos^2\theta/8-2i\sin\theta/8.\cos\theta/8}\\
\frac{1}{ia}=i\tan\theta/8\implies\boxed{a=-\cot\theta/8}
$$
Case 3: $1^{1/4}=-i$
$$
\frac{1}{ia}=\frac{ie^{i\theta/4}+1}{ie^{i\theta/4}-1}=\frac{1-\sin\theta/4+i\cos\theta/4}{-1-\sin\theta/4+i\cos\theta/4}\\
=\frac{1-\cos(\pi/2-\theta/4)+i\sin(\pi/2-\theta/4)}{-1-\cos(\pi/2-\theta/4)+i\sin(\pi/2-\theta/4)}\\
=\frac{2\sin^2(\pi/4-\theta/8)+2i\sin(\pi/4-\theta/8)\cos(\pi/4-\theta/8)}{-2\cos^2(\pi/4-\theta/8)+2i\sin(\pi/4-\theta/8)\cos(\pi/4-\theta/8)}\\
\frac{1}{ia}=-i\tan(\pi/4-\theta/8)\\
\boxed{a=\cot(\pi/4-\theta/8)=\tan(\pi/4+\theta/8)}
$$
Case 4: $1^{1/4}=i$
$$
\frac{1}{ia}=\frac{-ie^{i\theta/4}+1}{-ie^{i\theta/4}-1}=\frac{1+\sin\theta/4-i\cos\theta/4}{-1+\sin\theta/4-i\cos\theta/4}\\
=\frac{1+\cos(\pi/2-\theta/4)-i\sin(\pi/2-\theta/4)}{-1+\cos(\pi/2-\theta/4)-i\sin(\pi/2-\theta/4)}\\
=\frac{2\cos^2(\pi/4-\theta/8)-2i\sin(\pi/4-\theta/8)\cos(\pi/4-\theta/8)}{-2\sin^2(\pi/4-\theta/8)-2i\sin(\pi/4-\theta/8)\cos(\pi/4-\theta/8)}\\
=i.\cot(\pi/4-\theta/8)\\
\frac{1}{ia}=i\tan(\pi/4+\theta/8)\\
\boxed{a=-\cot(\pi/4+\theta/8)}
$$
Is it the right way to approach the problem ? and whats the easiest way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reality of the roots, take module on both sides :
$$\left|\frac{i-a}{-i-a}\right|=|z|^{1/4}=1$$
so if $A$ is the point of affix $a$, $I$ of affix $i$ and $I'$ of affix $-i$, this says that $AI=AI'$, so $A$ belongs to the perpendicular bisector of segment $[II']$, therefore the real axis.

For distinct roots, take argument : $(\overrightarrow{AI'};\overrightarrow{AI})=\frac14\arg(z)+k\frac\pi2$ with $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, this means 4 distinct points.

(There could be a better argument for last point).

With some calculus (which doesn't explain why roots are real) : let $z=e^{i\theta}$, and for $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, $\theta_k=\theta/4+k\pi/2$. Equation solves as 
$$a=\frac{e^{i\theta_k}-1}{i(e^{i\theta_k}+1)} = \frac{e^{i\theta_k/2}-e^{-i\theta_k/2}}{i(e^{i\theta_k/2}+e^{-i\theta_k/2})} = \tan(\theta_k/2) = \tan(\theta/8+k\pi/4)$$
OK, so it's real, but why ?

Comment: So u mean
$$
\frac{1+ia}{1-ia}=z^{1/4}1^{1/4}=e^{i\theta/4}(1,-1,i,-i)\\
ia=\frac{e^{i\theta/4}(1,-1,i,-i)-1}{e^{i\theta/4}(1,-1,i,-i)+1}=\frac{e^{i\theta_k}-1}{e^{i\theta_k}+1}\\\theta_k=\theta/4+\arg(1,-1,i,-i)=\theta/4+(0,\pi,\pi/2,3\pi/2)\\
ia=\frac{e^{i\theta_k/2}-e^{-i\theta_k/2}}{e^{i\theta_k/2}+e^{-i\theta_k/2}}=\frac{2i\sin(\theta_k/2)}{2\cos(\theta_k/2)}=i\tan(\theta_k/2)\\
a=\tan(\theta_k/2)=\begin{cases}
\tan(\theta/8)\\
\tan(\theta/8+\pi/2)=-\cot(\theta/8)\\
\tan(\theta/8+\pi/4)\\
\tan(\theta/8+3\pi/4)=-\cot(\theta/8+\pi/4)
\end{cases}
$$
right ?

Comment: Sort of. I don't like your "notation" $(1,i,-1,-i)$, and would certainly not use it with my students, but apart from this, I'm OK with what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\left|\dfrac{1+ia}{1-ia}\right|=1$$

WLOG 
$$\dfrac{1+ia}{1-ia}=\cos2t+i\sin2t=\dfrac{\cos t+i\sin t}{\cos t-i\sin t}$$ where $t$ is real

Using https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm,

$a=\tan t$

$\implies z=\cos8t+i\sin8t$

Now using   repeated root theorem like
 [How to solve $x^3=-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743),

$y^4=z$ can not have repeated roots

Comment: thanx. I understood till $z=e^{i8t}$ but from there how can I find the solutions and reach the required conclusion ?

Comment: i think didnt u assume $a\in\mathbb{R}$, but the question was to verify this right ?

Comment: @ss1729, I didn't