# How does $e^{5ix} = -1 $ have 5 solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers

Part of the solution to a question in my book says $e^{5ix} = -1 $ has five solutions for x. There is no further explanation. How do I arrive at this result?

Comment: Can you find one solution? If so, you can add any multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{5}$ to it and it will still be a solution. There are actually infinitely many solutions for $x$, but five possible values of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: The equation has infinitely many solutions: $x=\pi/5 +2k\pi/5$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$e^{i5x} = -1$$
is equivalent to 
$$\cos(5x) + i\sin(5x) = -1$$
because of Euler's formula. This obviously has infinite solutions for $n\geq1$ along $x=\pi\frac{2n-1}{5}$. I think it says $5$ because it has $5$ solutions for $0\leq x \lt 2\pi$.

Comment: This is the only proper answer so far.

Comment: You mean $0\le x\lt2\pi$. Of course $0$ and $2\pi$ have the same reference angle.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $2\pi$ is not a solution so it makes no difference, but I will add it anyways

Comment: @RyanShesler You are right, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

$e^{i\pi} = e^{3i\pi} = ... = e^{(2n-1)i\pi} = -1$

This has many solutions for,$$ 5x = 2n-1$$
$$x = \frac{2n - 1}{5}, n\epsilon Z$$
e.g.,

$ x = \frac{1}{5}$ or $ x = \frac{3}{5}$ or $ x = \frac{5}{5}$ or $ x = \frac{7}{5}$ or $ x = \frac{9}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

One solution is $$5x=\pi \implies x=\pi /5$$

Other solution come from  $$ 5x= 3\pi, 5\pi , 7\pi , 9\pi\implies x=3\pi/5, 5\pi/5, 7\pi/5, 9\pi/5$$

Answer (score 0):

If $e^{5ix}=e^{iy}$

$5ix=iy+2n\pi i$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=\dfrac{y+2n\pi}5,n=0,1,2,3,4$

Here one of the possible values of $y$ is $\pi$

Comment: I have a doubt actually, why can't n exceed 4?

Comment: @Hema, actually $n\equiv0,1,2,3,4\pmod5$ What's the period of $e^{iy}$

Comment: The period of $e^{ix}$ doesn't limit the number of solutions for $x$ in any way, which are real numbers.

Comment: If $y_m=e^{i(y+2m\pi)/5},$ $$y_u=y_v\implies$$ $2\pi$ divides $$\dfrac{y+2u\pi}5-\dfrac{y+2v\pi}5$$ $5$ divides $u-v$

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/192743#192743, $$x^5+1=0$$ doesn't have a repeated root

Comment: The equations $e^{5ix}+1=0$ and $x^5+1=0$ don't have the neither the same set of solutions not the same cardinality.

Comment: @user647486, Replace $e^{ix}$ with $y$

Comment: Do you understand that they don't? That $\pi/5+200000\pi/5$ is a very different real number than $\pi/5$? That change of variable gives the solutions $x$ of the original equation as a logarithm of $y$, which has infinitely many values.

Comment: @user647486,  How can $e^{5ix}+1=0$ and $x^5+1=0$ share common solutions!