# Finding cube roots of a unity - proper explanation is needed

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

### SQUARE ROOT

Let's say that I have:

\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 9
\end{align*}

And I $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$ an entire equation to get:

\begin{align*}
x_{1,2} &= \sqrt{9}\\
x_{1} &= +3\\
x_{2} &= -3
\end{align*}

Experience and *"fundamental theorem of algebra"* thought me that:

> There are always **two** square roots ($x_1$, $x_2$)!

Experience thought me that:

> Product of mixed roots doesn't return back the original:
> \begin{align*}
> x_1 \cdot x_2 &= -3 \cdot 3 = -9\\
> x_2 \cdot x_1 &= 3 \cdot (-3) = -9
> \end{align*}

Experience also thought me that:

> Only if roots are multiplied by itself they return back the result:
> \begin{align*}
> x_1 \cdot x_1 &= 3 \cdot 3 = 9\\
> x_2 \cdot x_2 &= (-3) \cdot (-3) = 9
> \end{align*}

---

### CUBE ROOT

Then there comes this:

\begin{align*}
x^3 &= 1\\
\end{align*}

If I $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$ an entire equation I get:

\begin{align*}
x_{1,2,3} &= \sqrt[3]{1}\\
x_1 &= 1\\
x_2 &= \text{???}\\
x_3 &= \text{???}
\end{align*}

Here I have no experience whatsoever but *"fundamental theorem of algebra"* says that:

> There are always **three** cube roots ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$)!

Now pay attention! Like for square root it should be true that:

> If roots $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are multiplied by **itself** they return $1$. Their mixed products will probably return something else.
> \begin{align*}
> x_1 \cdot x_1 \cdot x_1 = 1\\
> x_2 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_2 = 1\\
> x_3 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_3 = 1
> \end{align*}

So at this point everybody's already rushing to their paper and drawing this complex plane:

[image]

And in complex plane:

> If we multiply complex numbers, length of their position vectors multiply and their angles sum up.

So everybody will now draw $x_1$ on the $\mathbb{R}$ axis and tell me that this is the first root. I agree with that. Then they say:

> Length of a position vector of other two roots ($x_2$, $x_2$) must be $1$ as well.

And I agree with that. But what they say now, I can't agree with no matter how I look at it. They say:

> Because according to *"fundamental theorem of algebra"* there are **three** cube roots, and we will multiply them in order to get to $1$, angle between them must be $120^\circ$. We now start at $1$ and if we do a full circle we end at $1$ again. Woila! Problem solved...

I can't agree with this explanation as is because this only holds for $x_1$. If I take $x_1$ and make a full circle I end up getting $1$. But with $x_2$ and $x_3$ my starting point is not $1$. Starting points are actually:

\begin{align*}
\text{starting point for $x_2$:} \hspace{5mm} -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \\
\text{starting point for $x_3$:} \hspace{5mm} -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i
\end{align*}

And in case of $x_2$ and $x_3$ when we do a full circle we don't end up getting $1$, but we geometricaly looking end at positions:

\begin{align*}
-1/2 - \sqrt{3}/2 i \\
-1/2 + \sqrt{3}/2 i
\end{align*}

If the starting positions are as I state they are, angle that we need in order to get to the $1$ should be $\pm240/3 = \pm80^\circ$.

But then why does this explanation that they use, work? At the end of the day e.g. $x_2$ solves the problem:

\begin{align*}
\left(x_2\right)^3 &= 1\\
\left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right)^3 &= 1\\
\left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right)&= 1\\
\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}i - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}i + \frac{3}{4}i^2\right) \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) &= 1\\
\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{4}i - \frac{3}{4}\right) \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) &= 1\\
\left(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right) \left( -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) &= 1\\
\frac{1}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} i + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} i - \frac{3}{4} i^2 &= 1\\
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} &= 1
\end{align*}

I am sure there is something wrong with the explanation everybody are using but it is correct to assume roots are $120^\circ$ appart...

> Probably the point here is  not about making a full circle at all! Like most of the people say. It must be about adding conjugate pairs so that artifficialy we create enough roots to satisfy *fundamental theorem of algebra*! Thats all! So *odd number* root $3$ was historicaly first one that forced us to get out of the horizontal axis in complex plane and invent complex roots...

Can anyone present a **proper** explanation of why we choose $120^\circ$ for cube roots?

---

Comment: In the first case, $x_2\cdot x_2=9$, not $-9$.

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to understand why $120^{\circ}$ without using polar form. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: For the square root, technically it's $$\begin{align*}
x_{1,2} &=\pm \sqrt{9}\\
x_{1} &= +3\\
x_{2} &= -3
\end{align*}$$
The square root by definition returns _the positive solution_. Which is to say it always gives only $x_1$. Never $x_2$, never both.

Comment: @Arthur: which is the positive square root of $-1$?  Or of $-i$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1

Comment: @Henry Neither. Which is why you will basically never see me write $\sqrt{-1}$ or $\sqrt i$, except in two specific circumstances: 1) Discussing this very issue, and 2) The quadratic formula, just because everyone's a little hypocritical. (I'm sure if you dig around, you can find me using roots like this in the past. But it's been a while now, and I have lost nothing of value. When convenient and relevant, I always suggest to anyone and everyone that they too stop using the square root on negative or non-real numbers.)

Comment: @user798202 I fixed the $x_2 \cdot x_2 = 9$ typing error.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta I am familiar with a polar form. $x_1 = 1 \angle 0^\circ$, $x_2 = 1 \angle 120^\circ$, $x_3 = 1 \angle 240^\circ$. I know that when multiplied the lengths are multiplied and angles are summed.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no "first" root, "second" root, etc.

In the case of $x^2=1$, there are two roots, $-1$ and $1$. It is your choice to give these two roots whatever names you like.

In the case of $x^3=1$, there are three distinct roots. Again, it does not matter which one you call $x_1$.

In general, (complex) solutions to the equation $x^n=1$ together with complex multiplication form a group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity

This group tells you what happens when you multiply two solutions to the equations $x^n=1$.

---

I don't know where the "everybody explanation" is from; I would not do that anyway.

One way to find the three roots for $x^3=1$ is quite straightforward. Write $x=re^{i\theta}$ where $r\ge 0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Then

$$
(re^{i\theta})^3=1
$$
Taking the absolute value on both sides you get $r=1$. On the other hand,
$$
e^{i(3\theta)}=1
$$
which implies that $3\theta=2k\pi$ where $k$ is some integer. Now write
$$
\theta=\frac{2k\pi}{3},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
and pick the ones that are in $[0,2\pi)$. By periodicity, this is not a unique way to represent the roots. You could, for example, restrict $\theta$ to $[-\pi,\pi)$ at the beginning of the calculation.