# What is the easiest way to solve $z^3 = 1 + i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the easiest way to solve $z^3 = 1 + i$? I thought of remembering the unity roots of $$z^3, z^4, z^5,... z^n$$ but it sucks. I could use Euler's form or trigonometric but it's hard to get back to cartesian (rectangular) form. any ideas ? How would you solve any equations in the form $$z^n=c$$ $c$ is a complex number

Comment: Write $1+i$ as $re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: ok and then, I know it's a really simple case, sorry for that. That's what I did and got  $$e^{\frac{\pi*i}{4}}$$

Comment: Use De Moivre's Formula: If $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$, then $z^n = r^n(\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta))$.

Comment: It's often useful to know that $(1+i)^2 = 2i$.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to solve $x^3=-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/how-to-solve-x3-1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c=re^{i\phi}$. Then
$$
c^{\frac1n}=r^{\frac1n}e^{i\left(\frac\phi n+\frac{2\pi}n k\right)}
=r^{\frac1n}\left[\cos\left(\frac\phi n+\frac{2\pi}n k\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\phi n+\frac{2\pi}n k\right)\right],
$$
with $k=0\dots n-1$.

In your example $r=\sqrt2$, $\phi=\frac\pi4$.